# acepting data from xml file with spring and tomcat

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have some devices that are sending some data as xml file pointing to some ip and port - right now for it I have small service which accept that files, parse it and make record to database. There is also another web application with UI, that users work with it. This application takes that data from database and and represent it to a user with reports etc. For it I am using tomcat with spring. Now, I would like to make this small service as a part of this web application also using spring and tomcat so I can make better processing with data. This way I have two separated application - one are parsing xml data and recording it to database and other which is for users. Problem is that that device can hit only ip:port. Is this possible to achieve (if someone understand me :) )? Is there some example or someone have some advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can let one application forward requests to the other.
That way the client only has to connect to the first one.

You can find a discussion  on how to do that at

Its important that you understand the difference between 
'forward' - happens on the server (I would try this in your case)
and
'redirect' - happens on the client

Both is explained here and also how to do this with spring.

[spring-redirect-and-forward](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-redirect-and-forward)

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, I was hoping I can solve it inside one application, I will check your suggestion...